# How come the CountourPlots of `u^4/12 == a^4/6` and `u == (2)^(1/4)*a` do not overlay perfectly?

Tags: plotting

How come the two following ContourPlots do not overlay perfectly?

```
p4 := ContourPlot[u^4/12 == a^4/6, {u, 0, 3}, {a, 0, 3}, ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> Red, Background -> White]

p5 := ContourPlot[u == (2)^(1/4)*a, {u, 0, 3}, {a, 0, 3}, ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> Magenta, Background -> White]

Show[p4, p5]
```

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the number of `PlotPoints`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and/or the [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ContourPlot[{u^4/12 == a^4/6, u == 2^(1/4)*a},
 {u, 0, 3}, {a, 0, 3},
 ContourShading -> False,
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Magenta},
 Background -> White,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]